# What are the other 2 mnemonics represent for when I launch ganache?

Tags: private-blockchain, ganache

I download the Ganache on Windows, it gives me 10 accounts and 12 mnemonics when I launch it, I think that the first 10 mnemonics are represent for 10 accounts, but what are the other 2 mnemonics "subway" and "mouse" represent for? I cant catch that...so can anybody help me about this? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact those 12 words are 1 mnemonics used to generate those 10 accounts.

They are following the [BIP 44](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki)  (Multi-Account Hierarchy for Deterministic Wallets) specification which is the same for a lot of blockchain.

You can see a bit more how it works [here](https://iancoleman.io/bip39/) just enter your 12 words as mnemonics and see how are generated multiple accounts with it

Comment: so the mnemonic is made up of the 12 words? If only I remember the mnemonic, I can get the same 10 accounts, is that right?

Comment: Yup you got it. If you got metamask you can actually test this. Restaure your account using those 12 words. Connect to ganache using http://127.0.0.1:7595. 
You'll see first only one account with 100 ethers and if you want to see the others you can "create" more account and they'll have 100 ethers too.

Comment: OK! You help me a lot, thx! :)